# Driver Of A Fax Modem Needed : Conextant HSFI CX11252-16Z Driver For Win XP

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, modem

I really really need the driver of a fax modem: `Conextant HSFI CX11252-16Z` driver for Win XP.
I've searched thousands of times using Google and other search engines and really don't know what is going on about web site drivers!!!!
I couldn't find a link for download and always there was a survey there.
Please help me, I know this modem is too old but I really need it.

Comment: You could try contacting the [manufacturer](http://www.conexant.com/aboutConexant/contact/Pages/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already visited and discounted Driversguide.com?
http://members.driverguide.com/driver_search.php?q=Conextant+HSFI+CX11252-16Z&si=ef0a6ea499ce2c92525b8b7fc0d6ba4e&st=1357311620&gqm0=Conextant+HSFI+CX11252-16Z
Using the DriversGuide installer is annoying, but they will let you download the driver for free.  You don't have to sign up with DriversGuide.

Look at that list I gave you a link to.

- Click the Download>> button
- You are brought to the file details page.  Click the big Green Download Now button.  Yes, leave the little check box under it checked.  Again, using the DriversGuide installer is free.
- type the phrase they want you to type.
- wait for the DriversGuide installer to download.  Run it.
- CAREFULLY READ before you click everything.

  - The first page of the installer confirms the file that is going to be downloaded, so go ahead and click Next Step.
  - Obviously you don't want the silly browser bars, so uncheck those before you click the Next Step button.
  - The next page is tricky... notice that it STILL SAYS Step 2 of 4 (just like the previous) and it tells you that *IF* you click the next step button you agree to Yontoo.  Just uncheck the box and click the Next Step.
  - The next page again STILL SAYS step 2 of 4, and gives you a Decline button.  Click that.
  - The software downloads at this point, and the page finally says 3 of 4, so click Next Step.
  - You are taken to the Thank You page, and can click Done.

WHEW!  ( just downloaded the first two drivers in the list I gave you a link to CX11252-16Z.zip and cx_11252-16z_WinXP.rar because I wanted to make sure that you could still get them for free AND I wanted to detail the process)

Yes.  That is quite annoying.  I've been using DriversGuide since... I think 1997?  I remember using it to download some drivers when I was in New Orleans.  Driversguide.com never used to have such a convoluted system, BUT in order to continue to provide them for free, they have evolved this very ugly distribution system.  Again, if you read carefully what you are presented with, you can walk away with the drivers you want WITHOUT signing up for the site, WITHOUT adding any spyware or browser bars, and WITHOUT paying anything.

Do it once or twice, and you might find you end up bookmarking DriversGuide for future use.